# Packing a Laravel4 or Symfony2 command in a phar archive

Tags: symfony, laravel, laravel-4, phar, iron

I'm looking into using IronWorker to run a number of scheduled tasks.
(http://dev.iron.io/worker/)

For this to work I need to be able to package everything I need, before sending it to Iron. And when I do, I need to be able to say 'php ' to actually run it.

However, in the case of my current (Laravel 4) project, a command is actually run as "php artisan command:commandname".

My question:
How can I package the entire Laravel installation into a phar archive, and have that phar point directly to the execution of that one specific command?

(Note: If anyone knows how to do this for Symfony2, go ahead, I'm sure both are quite similar)

Thanks,

Dieter